# Btrfs subvolume for 2 distros

Tags: btrfs

I use btrfs as my filesystem from one year. I have a question. 
Can I use one partition with two root subvolume  of two different distros? 
For example, /dev/sda2 contain subvolume root arch (@), if I renonym @ in @arch, can I create in sda2 new subvolume @gentoo?

Comment: here's also [very good instruction](https://medium.com/@teejeetech/linux-multiboot-with-btrfs-luks-and-efi-part-2-7b0896c03cce) how to do exactly that with two or "any number" of distros, including multiboot and even encryption of the btrfs. It's quite straight forward to leave out the encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can! Eh eh. 
Currently I have five distros in one partition, with five subvolumes for roots and another partition with five subvolumes for home.